What is the best t-test to compare two groups with a confounding factor and unequal sample size in each group?
I am working on my  master thesis and came up with a problem. I want to validate if changing the raw material for a chemical reaction would give the same yield of my product of interest. First, I did experiment 1 at working conditions X,Y and compound A to produce B; later, I did experiment 2 at the same working conditions of experiment 1 (X,Y) but using compound C to obtain the same product B. I collected samples to calculate the yield of B over different times of reaction but not equally spaced, so I ended up with different sample size (79 for exp 1 - Blue line, 69 for exp 2 - Orange line) as shown in the graph.

First, I thought of using a two-sample t-test; however, I was told that the experiments performed are not totally independentent because I used the same conditions X,Y that would act as confounding factors. Then, they suggested using a paired t-test.
After reading about this test, I realized that I can not calculate it because I have unequal sample size; also, the samples were randomly collected along the experiment, so there is not case pairing.
I have seen more alternatives like Welch's t-test, Wilcoxon rank sum test, Permutation test or Bootstrap method. But i am not sure if they will work for my situation.
In summary, I feel in a dead-end alley and I would like to ask... What would be the best comparison test that fit to my case? Thank you for your help.

Having the same conditions in both runs is not a confounding factor for the comparison that you are proposing, and the different sample sizes reduce the efficiency of the test but don't otherwise matter. However, before launching into a statistical analysis you should explore the results that you have in hand with graphical displays, and bear in mind that you have done a preliminary study that might be best used as a guide for a more carefully designed test.

If you think that the time of sampling is important then you probably should not be thinking in terms of a t-test, as it would only deal with the mean value rather than the rate of product generation in the reaction.

Thank you for your time to response! I edited my original question and included a graph to make it clearer. In deed there is a tendency and change over time more pronounced for compound B until reaching a kind of steady state. Could it be possible to use t-test using only the data after 50 hours for example? That would prove graphically and numerically the difference?

Why do you want to do a t-test? The two compounds yield vastly different reaction kinetics. That looks more interesting to me than the steady-state yield of compound B. Performing a t-test on the data from a single time point would ignore most of the information that is in the graph.

Thank you very much for your opinion, I've been checking some literature and I agree with you. I think it's better to discuss about the trend rather than averge values and compare it with t-test

Since working conditions are held constant, I don't see a risk of confounding, but I'm not sure your experiment answers the question you want.
I'm operating under the assumption that reactions take time, and in time means that the yield should be different at different times.  Hence, while working conditions are held constant, the sampling in time can change the mean yield -- if you sampled soon after the start, then this means lower yield.  If you sampled later, this means more yield. Correct me if I am wrong.
If your goal is to estimate yield, I might do the following:

Hold operating conditions constant.
Replicate the experiment $N$ times for each compound A and C.
There is no reason to believe that experiments within paired strata (e.g. the two first experiments) have some sort of strata level effect (like a bias) so I don't see any advantage over of pairing observations.
Run a Welch's t-test since a) it might be reasonable that the variance changes between compounds, and b) if not then you sacrifice a bit of statistical power, which can be made up by doing more experiments.

The key here would be to measure yield at the same point in time, rather than sampling in time.  Above, $N$ can be determined with a straight forward sample size calculation.
How feasible this is depends on exactly what you're doing.  If you provide more context, I can edit my answer where needed to be maximally helpful.

Thank you very much for your response! I really appreciate. I edited my original question and added a graph of the data set that I have to make it clearer.
As you mention, the yield of the reaction changed over time and looks like it would reach a steady state. I can't repeat the experiments, basically I have to get the most conclusions out of the data I have now. The two-sample t-test gave a significant difference using the whole data sets for each group.

How could compound C yield MORE of product B early and then less later on?  Is this a rate of yield or something?

Additionally, because your yield changes in time, the T test is probably not appropriate and you're going to have to model the yield.

Based on the graphs you added, the answer is obvious, and trivial!. Compund C produces a higher yield than compound A at all time points! In addition, compound C produces a much higher yield in much shorter time! So compound C wins (more product B, faster), w/o the need for any statistical test. The graph should "hit you between the eyes", and should be all you need to justify using compound C (unless there is an error in the graph? Indeed, why would yield for C drop over time?)

Thank you both for your responses. After checking some literature I agree with your perspective. I thought maybe a t-test will be better to out a number and highlight the differences; however, in situations like this, maybe a simplier way like a graph is better and more informative
